problemas para mostrar selección en fpdf
Tento una consulta con dos resultados pero me imprime siempre el mismo valor dos veces y el otro no lo muestra.
Funcion para seleccionar datos

public function ndedetalles($idencabezado)
{
    $sql = "SELECT a.nombre AS articulo, a.codigo, d.canart, d.precio_mov, d.descuento, (d.canart*d.precio_mov-d.descuento) AS subtotal,d.destino,d.observacion FROM detalle_mov d INNER JOIN articulo a ON d.idarticulo=a.idarticulo WHERE d.idencabezado='$idencabezado'";
    return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
}

Codigo en mi fpdf
$rsptav = $venta->ndecabecera($_GET["id"]);
$regv = $rsptav->fetch_assoc();
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$encontrados = $rsptav->num_rows;
 for ($i=0; $i < $encontrados; $i++) { 

  $pdf->Ln(0.6);
  $pdf->SetX(24);
  $pdf->Cell(22, 5, $regv['codigo'], 0, 0, 'L', 0);
  $pdf->Cell(111, 5, $regv['articulo'], 0, 0, 'L', 0);
  $pdf->Cell(32, 5, $regv['canart'] . ' - ' . $regv['precio_mov'], 0, 1, 'C', 0);
 }


No falta especificarle la fila a $regv['codigo']???

A que haces referencia cuando dices especificar la fila ? porqué el nombre de la fila es el que esta entre cada corchete codigo, articulo, canart, esos son los nombres de mis filas.. lo que requiero es que me muestre toda la consulta que son dos resultados, me regresa dos pero imprime solo el segundo dos veces..

esa es la columna, no la fila ;) mira la doc... https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php... trajiste una sola fila segun eso...

Como ya te comentaron, el error se debe a que al realizar el bucle for siempre estás imprimiendo los mismos datos que obtuviste al realizar $regv = $rsptav->fetch_assoc();.
Dichos datos no van a cambiar hasta que realices nuevamente una llamada a dicha función.
Solución:
Por lo general, para obtener uno a uno e iterar los resultados de una consulta se utiliza while, por ejemplo, así:
$rsptav = $venta->ndecabecera($_GET["id"]);
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$encontrados = $rsptav->num_rows;
while ($regv = $rsptav->fetch_assoc()) { 

  $pdf->Ln(0.6);
  $pdf->SetX(24);
  $pdf->Cell(22, 5, $regv['codigo'], 0, 0, 'L', 0);
  $pdf->Cell(111, 5, $regv['articulo'], 0, 0, 'L', 0);
  $pdf->Cell(32, 5, $regv['canart'] . ' - ' . $regv['precio_mov'], 0, 1, 'C', 0);
 }

